# HttpURLConnection exception

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have a method to check for internet connectivity within the device.The method always throws exception even though the mobile is connected to wifi/gprs. Do i need to add any 
permission within xml or is the code gone wrong

```
public boolean checkConnectivity(String url)  {     

        try{                

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

                if(conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        return true;
                }else{
                        return false;
                }

        }catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("myhttp exception");
                return false;
        }                           
}
```

Comment: Have you declare internet permission in android manifest file . If No then please declare internet permission in manifest file.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: Try posting the error, also you CANNOT establish a net connection on the UI thread. It is illegal.

Comment: i added the permission even then i get same exception .. now the exception is java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream

Comment: can you post your url please ?

Comment: what is your exception? e.toString()?

Comment: try this: remove `conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");` or change it to `conn.setRequestMethod("POST");`

Comment: seems than url is causing problem, url : http://earthtools.org but the website seems to open up perfectly.. hmmm

Comment: nope if the url is given directly it throws malformed url exception

Comment: guess i'll have to use a different logic all together :(

Comment: can you open it in browser of your device?

Comment: yes the site opens up properly, when i use http://google.com there is no exception thrown but the method returns false which should not be the case..

Comment: I tried your code and it returns me true.

Comment: really wiered, for some reason i can't seem to get it work. Thanks chirag for updates :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following permission to your Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Also, I would recommend using the Connectivity Manager Service for doing this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html